# tensorflow module not found, while using streamlit

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, streamlit

PS D:\projects\fashion-recommender-system> streamlit run main1.py

You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

Local URL: http://localhost:8501
Network URL: http://192.168.1.213:8501

2022-05-04 14:12:41.903 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\prana\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 443, in *run_script
exec(code, module.**dict**)
File "D:\projects\fashion-recommender-system\main1.py", line 1, in 
import tensorflow
File "C:\Users\prana\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow_*init**.py", line 37, in 
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'

above is the output of terminal.
tensorflow is installed in python and does work when I run python file, but when I run the python file using streamlit run main.py, It doesn't find any tensorflow module.

I have installed python versions of 3.9 and 3.7
In 3.7 python shell when I import tensorflow, there is no error
In 3.9 python shell when I import tensorflow there is error

when I run pip --version command it gives me this warning
pip --version
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 22.0.4 from C:\Users\prana\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

I don't know what is causing streamlit to not found tensorflow module, please help me.

Comment: Try to run:
`PS D:\projects\fashion-recommender-system> python -V`

What version is it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.